# Replace underscores to whitespaces using bash script

Tags: bash, whitespace

How can I replace all underscore chars with a whitespace in multiple file names using Bash Script? Using this code we can replace underscore with dash. But how it works with whitespace?

```
for i in *.mp3;
do x=$(echo $i | grep '_' | sed 's/_/\-/g');
if [ -n "$x" ];
then mv $i $x;
fi;
done;
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should do:

```
for i in *.mp3; do
    [[ "$i" = *_* ]] && mv -nv -- "$i" "${i//_/ }"
done
```

- The test `[[ "$i" = *_* ]]` tests if file name contains any underscore and if it does, will `mv` the file, where `"${i//_/ }"` expands to `i` where all the underscores have been replaced with a space (see [shell parameter expansions](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)).
- The option `-n` to `mv` means `no clobber`: will not overwrite any existent file (quite safe). *Optional*.
- The option `-v` to `mv` is for `verbose`: will say what it's doing (if you want to see what's happening). *Very optional*.
- The `--` is here to tell `mv` that the arguments will start right here. This is always good practice, as if a file name starts with a `-`, `mv` will try to interpret it as an option, and your script will fail. *Very good practice*.

Another comment: When using globs (i.e., `for i in *.mp3`), it's always very good to either set `shopt -s nullglob` or `shopt -s failglob`. The former will make `*.mp3` expand to nothing if no files match the pattern (so the loop will not be executed), the latter will explicitly raise an error. Without these options, if no files matching `*.mp3` are present, the code inside loop will be executed with `i` having the verbatim value `*.mp3` which can cause problems. (well, there won't be any problems here because of the guard `[[ "$i" = *_* ]]`, but it's a good habit to always use either option).

Hope this helps!

Comment: ... could be better written `[[ "$i" == "*_*" ]]` as this make less confusion while `==` is used for test and `=` for assign (at all I didn't found syntax `[[ LHS = RHS ]]` in manpage).

Comment: @F.Hauri Scroll down near the bottom of section _Bash Conditional Expressions_ of the [bash reference manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions) for `=` used with `[[`. Otherwise, you shouldn't quote the `*_*` in the right-hand side. So what I wrote is correct.

Comment: Thanks, I found it!. Two syntax seem to be alias for *POSIX* conformance. At all, new syntax is less confuse.

Answer (score 3):

The reason your script is failing with spaces is that the filename gets treated as multiple arguments when passed to `mv`. You'll need to quote the filenames so that each filename is treated as a single agrument. Update the relevant line in your script with:

```
mv "$i" "$x"  
# where $i is your original filename, and $x is the new name
```

As an aside, if you have the [perl version of the rename command](http://man.he.net/man1/rename) installed, you skip the script and achieve the same thing using:

```
rename 's/_/ /' *.mp3
```

Or if you have the [more classic `rename` command](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rename):

```
rename "_" " " *.mp3
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `tr`

```
tr '_' ' ' <file1 >file2
```

Comment: why the pipes (`|`)? does that even work? `tr '_' ' ' <file1 >file2` should be enough, to redirect input and output